# jade nesting and nodejs

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to find a better way to express this in jade:

```
    p.author.alignleft 
      | Posted by 
      | admin 
      | in
      | Uncategorized
```

The above works, but i'm wondering if there is a way to do it without using the  tags. I can't seem to make it work any other way than what is above.  NB, the word "admin" and "uncategorized" are actually a href's. I gave up trying to get it to display right in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.author.alignleft Posted by
  a(href:'#') admin
  | in
  a(href:'#') Uncategorized
```